# Sorting in Controller before paginate() in CakePHP

Tags: php, sorting, cakephp, pagination

So I have this cute little index function in my ItemsController:

```
public function index() {
        $this->Item->recursive = 2;
        $this->set('items', $this->paginate());
    }
```

It's like this because I am doing a bunch of calculations on afterFind (adding a field, and sorting by it)

But I want to sort on the Controller level so that I can have a recent(), etc.
If I sort on the afterFind level, it'll sort like that every time no matter what the controller - so that's no good.

How do I sort on the controller level and still be able to use $this->paginate() correctly?

FYI Here is some of my AfterFind:

```
public function afterFind($results, $primary = false){
    parent::afterFind($results, $primary);
    foreach ($results as $key => $val) {
        // my foreach logic calculating Item.score  
    }
// the stuff I should be doing on a controller-to-controller basis:
    $results = Set::sort($results, '{n}.Item.score', 'desc'); 
    return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you use sort using Paginator

```php
public function index() {
  $this->paginate = array(
    'limit' => 10,
    'order' => array( // sets a default order to sort by
      'Item.name' => 'asc'
    )
  );
  $items = $this->paginate('Item');
  $this->set(compact('items'));
}
```

In your view:

```html
<div class="sort-buttons">
  Sort by
  <?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('name', 'By Name', array('class' => 'button')); ?>
  <?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('score', 'By Score', array('class' => 'button')); ?>
  <?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('date', 'By Date', array('class' => 'button')); ?>
</div><!-- /.sort-buttons -->
```

Or, if using to create a REST API, use query strings:

```
http://myapp.dev/items/index?sort=score&direction=desc
```

Comment: Thanks I think this is what I'm looking for - except it's not working. Could it be because 'score' field doesn't exist in the db and is just being inserted in the afterFind?

Comment: FYI the issue was that I didn't declare it as a Virtual Field. Once I did that - I set it to the an arbitrary existing field, and then calculated it in the afterFind. Changing the fields to what they need to be. There is prob a better, lower overhead way of doing this. But it worked.

Comment: ^ I wonder if you might want to calculate the value of this virtual field directly in the model instead of afterFind()? Documentation on Virtual fields: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html

Answer (score 1):

The working way for me was into the controller:

```
/******************************************************************
 * 
 ******************************************************************/
function admin_index() {
    $this->paginate = array(
        'News' => array(
            'order' => array(
                'News.created' =>  'DESC'
            )
        )
    );
    $data = $this->paginate('News');
    $this->set('news', $data);
}
```